# Outlook desktop application add-in to insert mail addresses to outlook new mail To address bar

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-js

I have an Outlook add-in develop for Outlook 2016 desktop application.
I want to add mail addresses to new outlook To address field through my outlook add-in,
When I type mail addresses in my outlook add-in and press insert button, then those addresses should go to the To addresses in the Outlook new mail.

Note: My aim is to work with Outlook desktop application and not for Outlook 365.

Could anyone tell me a way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Office.context.mailbox.item` object has `to` property which you able to use to manipulate with recipients list by using `setAsync` and `getAsync` functions. The doc ... [Office.context.mailbox.item.to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item#to-arrayemailaddressdetailsjavascriptapioutlook17officeemailaddressdetailsrecipientsjavascriptapioutlook17officerecipients). The following is the example from the documentation ...

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.to.setAsync( ['alice@contoso.com', 'bob@contoso.com'] );
Office.context.mailbox.item.to.addAsync( ['jason@contoso.com'] );
Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync(callback);

function callback(asyncResult) {
  var arrayOfToRecipients = asyncResult.value;
}
```